# Showing random letters as attribute values instead of array items

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to generate a registration box with javascript, and I've managed to do so until I stumbled upon a weird bug. The script outputs this in the HTML:

```
<input type="f" name="i" alt="r" placeholder="s">
```

Instead of:

```
<input type="email" name="regemail" alt="email" placeholder="What's your email?">
```

And the same goes for the other 2 inputs. Why is this happening? I've tried to look for any errors but the console isn't giving me any errors and I can't find anything wrong with the code I've written. Help is appreciated.

```js
var firstInput = ["email", "regemail", "email", "What's your email?"];
    var secondInput = ["password", "regpassword", "password", "Choose a password"];
    var thirdInput = ["password", "confirmpassword", "confirmpassword", "Confirm password"];
    var types = ["type", "name", "alt", "placeholder"];
    var inputNumber = ["firstInput", "secondInput", "thirdInput"];
    var container = document.getElementById('usp-container');

    function register() {

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('id', "register-popup");
    container.appendChild(div);
    
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.setAttribute('method', "post");
    form.setAttribute('action', "processregistration.php");
    div.appendChild(form);
    
    
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            
        function makeInputs(inputs) {
            
        var tableRow = document.createElement('tr');
        form.appendChild(tableRow);
        var tableData = document.createElement('td');
        tableRow.appendChild(tableData);
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            
            input.setAttribute(types[j], inputs[j]);
        }
            
        tableData.appendChild(input);
        
        }
            
        makeInputs(inputNumber[i]);
    }
    
    }

    register();
```

Comment: You should move the makeInputs function outside of the register function. If you take a look at this fiddle, and click JSHint, it will show you that warning on the side. http://jsfiddle.net/ej4e2p3L/

Comment: What difference does it make? And, any idea why the inputs are ignoring the CSS regarding margin left and right? It works when u write the markup in the HTML directly but when Javascript generated it aligns to the left instead of in the middle..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the variable names in an array

```
var firstInput = ["email", "regemail", "email", "What's your email?"];

var inputNumber = ["firstInput", "secondInput", "thirdInput"];
```

Then you're iterating over those variable names, and trying to get the value of that variable with

```
inputNumber[0]
```

and that gets you the string `"firstInput"`, **not** an array, so when you do

```
inputNumber[0][0]
```

you get the character `"f"`, **not** the value `"email"` from the array.

To use a string to reference a variable you would have to use bracket notation, and in the global scope that would look something like

```
window[inputNumber[0]][0];
```

which is really not a very good way to get the variable

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uvmtjf28/1/)

You would be better of with an object

```
var values = {
    firstInput  : ["email", "regemail", "email", "What's your email?"],
    secondInput : ["password", "regpassword", "password", "Choose a password"],
    thirdInput  : ["password", "confirmpassword", "confirmpassword", "Confirm password"]
}
```

then referencing the arrays with key names

```
values[inputNumber[0]][0]
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uvmtjf28/2/)

Comment: Superb answer, two questions though. 
- window[inputs][j], what does the window actually stand for? 
- why are objects better than the previous solution?

Comment: `window` is the global object, when you define a variable in the global scope with `var variable` it's added to the global object, which is `window` and that's why you can do `window['variable']` to get it etc.